# android betatesting sites needed

Tags: android, beta-testing

I have created the Android version of an ios app and am looking for beta-testers. For ios there are at least 2 quite well-managed sites, but for Android I only found a forum where I can post my apk: http://androidforums.com/alpha-beta-testing/
Is there any other site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, have you tried http://zubhi.co , we always use it for android betas.